# Filter a list using REST by a multiple user column

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

How can I use REST API to filter a list by a multiple user column?

I'm trying this right now

```
  "$filter=multipleUserColumn eq " + currentUserID
```

I want to make a custom view that shows the items where the current user is one of the users in that column.

Comment: Please refer this link --> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a84aca7-8f8e-43e5-b579-76adf8a55369/rest-api-to-filter-multi-selection-user-field?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious